# CodeIgniter: Loading view in new window

Tags: php, codeigniter

Im writing a script that allows users to preview their reports before saving them to the database using CodeIgniter.

Using the `$this->load->view('preview_report', $data);` tag.

Is there anything i can add to this string to make it load into a new browser window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have different functions (or controllers) for creating and previewing reports, for example http://localhost/appname/report/create and http://localhost/appname/report/preview, you can open new browser window when calling preview function, using basic stuff like

```
<a href="http://localhost/appname/report/preview" target="_blank" >PREVIEW REPORT</a>
```

and your report will open **in new window**. if this is what you want.

Comment: I cant run this from the controller though can i?

Comment: Ahhh do it from the view ... Got it ... Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

If 'load into a new browser' refers to 'popup window', then I don't think PHP itself can help you create popup window without the use of Javascript.

Have a look at this page: http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/61395/#302107