# Load a codeigniter view in a new window

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I am looking for a way to open a report in a new window using codeigniter. 
Still I did not find a proper way to do this. I need to send an array of data to this view as well and I think that won't be a big problem as following code normally used to pass an array of data to a view.

```
$this->load->view('report',$data);
```

My problem is how to open it in a new window using JavaScript,jQuery or PHP if there is a method.
Some help will be really helpful.
Thanks.

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6009113/codeigniter-loading-view-in-new-window

Comment: You can do it with link. For example: <a href="<?php echo base_url('Controller/Method')?> target='_blank' >" When you click the link report opened in window

Comment: yes, I understand that this works for a link very well. My requirement is to open a report in a new window and pass an array of data to that so I can use that array to display relevant data. this window will popup at a button click. thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
echo anchor('controller/function', 'Show in New Window', array('target' = > '_blank'));
```

Or maybe you can use JQuery trick

Answer (score 0):

Using HTML you can open your link in new page like :

```
<a href="link of report loding controller/function" target="_blank" >REPORT</a>
```